# How to count distinct rows

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have looked into many similar topics but the issue was not resolved anywhere in stackoverflow.
I have table:

```
name|something
john,blabla
john,xdxdxd
john,15kusdprogrammer
eve,givebackrib
malcolm,anything
eve,welcome
eve,to
eve,internet
```

I would like to get distinct name with counted rows - SQL query looks like this:

```
select distinct name,count(*) from TABLE_NAME group by name order by 2 desc;
```

and the result looks like:

```
eve,4
john,3
malcolm,1
```

I've tried to create flask-sqlalchemy query like this:

```
TABLE_NAME.query.distinct(TABLE_NAME.name).with_entities(TABLE_NAME.name, count(TABLE_NAME.something)).all()
```

but the only one solution which I have created is this one:

```
for name in TABLE_NAME.query.distinct(TABLE_NAME.name).with_entities(TABLE_NAME.name).all():
print("{}: {}".format(name, TABLE_NAME.query.filter(TABLE_NAME.name== name[0]).count()))
```

but queries in for loop takes huge amount of time.
Can someone please help me create the flask-sqlalchemy query from sqlite code:

```
select distinct name,count(*) from TABLE_NAME group by name order by 2 desc;
```

Comment: If you're using `GROUP BY` you don't need the `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
TABLE_NAME.query(TABLE_NAME.name, func.count(TABLE_NAME.name).label('count')).group_by(TABLE_NAME.name).all()
```

and with the order by count it should look like

```
TABLE_NAME.query(TABLE_NAME.name, func.count(TABLE_NAME.name).label('count')).group_by(TABLE_NAME.name).order_by(desc(func.count(TABLE_NAME.name))).all()
```

sqlalchemy function [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/functions.html)